# Mechanism of Hofmann Rearrangement Reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds, amines

In the Hofmann Rearrangement Reaction (in basic medium), when $\ce{RNH-}$ ion is produced, why does it not attack $\ce{Br2}$  or take $\ce{H+}$from the amide itself?
Also, why does it take $\ce{H+}$ from water only?

Comment: How much water is there and how much of everything else is there?

Comment: @jerepierre, we have taken bromine in excess and 1 equivalent of water.

Comment: It's very unlikely that there's only one equivalent of water...

Comment: @jerepierre, the reaction conditions state that there are 3 eq. of NaOH,   Br2 and 1 eq. water.

Comment: @jerepierre, it is also given that, sometimes we don't require water as it gets produced in the reaction itself.

Comment: @Ayushmaan Wait, wait, wait. There are 3 equivalents of sodium hydroxide and no water? Is it just a solid sitting at the bottom of the flask?

Comment: Most of the steps in the mechanism are reversible,  especially the proton transfers. So, the exact source of a proton doesn't matter, as that proton might have been exchanged with other protons many times before. Except for the actual rearrangement (i.e. the isocyanate forming step), most are reversible steps.

Comment: @Zhe, I meant to say that the solvent doesn't matter, as long as it does not hinder OH- attack.

Comment: @EashaanGodbole but won't it help reduce the amount of NaOH required in the reaction?

Comment: Review the mechanism of the reaction. The NaOH is required stoichiometrically. You need that much...

Comment: In Hoffmann Rearrangement water is used as solvent, so much more than 1 equivalent is added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Water is present in large excess when compared to the amide, so it is statistically not likely that the proton would be removed from the amide rather then water. Even if it happens, proton exchange is reversible so it would be formed/unformed many times that eventually the removal of the proton by water would happen and proceed with the mechanism.

Regarding the attack to $\ce{Br2}$, I believe the reason it doesn't happen is that the ion would be surrounded by many many water molecules because: 1) the amide forms H-bonds with water, 2) the ion is solvated efficiently by water, so more molecules would be around to have their protons removed.